# Jquery AJAX Save to file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Everthing here works fine except that in the saved file it doesn't give me the whole string. Just one of the IDs (There are multiple on the page).

Not sure how get "all of the IDs and Content" in the $.ajax()

What am I doing wrong?

Have got this jquery:

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click',function(){
var contentMap = {};
$('[id^="appendHeading"]').each(function(){
    contentMap[this.id] = $(this).text();
});
for(id in contentMap)
    $("#PrintIds").append("ObjectID:" + id + "Content:" + contentMap[id]);

$.ajax({
  url: "post.php",
  type: "post",
  data: { 
      objectID: id,
      content: contentMap[id]
      },
      success: function(){
      alert("success");
  },
  error:function(){
      alert("failure");
  }   
 }); 
});
```

And this PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['objectID'] || $_POST['content']) {
$myFile = "test.css";
$stringData = $_POST['objectID'] || $_POST['content'];
file_put_contents($myFile,$stringData);
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you expect `$stringData = $_POST['objectID'] || $_POST['content'];` to do?

Comment: I want to put the values from $_POST['objectID'] and $_POST['content'] in the $myFile so the output may be something like "#objectID1: theobject1, Content1:thecontent1,#objectID2: theobject2, Content2:thecontent2"

Comment: `||` is a logical OR. Replace it with a `.` and see if that works.

Comment: Ofcourse! Thanks! (Seems like I better go to sleep soon...) hehe

Comment: But still it only gives me the first #Object and not the second from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to enclosed the `for` loop into `{` and `}`.

```
$('a#exportPage').on('click',function(){
var contentMap = {};
$('[id^="appendHeading"]').each(function(){
    contentMap[this.id] = $(this).text();
});
for(id in contentMap) {
    $("#PrintIds").append("ObjectID:" + id + "Content:" + contentMap[id]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "post.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { 
            objectID: id,
            content: contentMap[id]
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }   
    }); 
}
});
```

The content should be appended to the end of the file:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['objectID'] || $_POST['content']) {
    $myFile = "test.css";
    $stringData = $_POST['objectID'] . ':' . $_POST['content'] . "\n";
    file_put_contents($myFile,$stringData,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't do it! But I think I've did something wrong in the declaration of the variables in the $ajax() but can't figure out exactly what!

Comment: Sorry man! I missed the whole Jquery you wrote, just saw the PHP! It works brilliant now! Thank you for your time!