# Pass variable from Javascript to PHP to write to file

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

It could be duplicate cause unable to find answer even by searching similar questions of Stackoverflow. This is what I am trying to do. I need to pass a stored variable in JavaScript to PHP which would write it to temp file 'yy.html'. I could get alert from the submit function but not the temp file. I get temp file when I run PHP alone.

**g.htm**

```
<html>
<head><title>Hide and Seek</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id = "nextbutton"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
res = "Hide & Seek";
document.getElementById('nextbutton').innerHTML = '<button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-u-default" OnClick="javascript:submit()">Restart</button>&nbsp;&nbsp';
function submit()
{
alert(res);
$.post('my.php', { postres: res} );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**my.php**

```
<?php $res = $_POST['postres']; $temp = getenv("TEMP"); file_put_contents($temp . "/yy.html", $res); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post

Comment: Are you including jQuery anywhere?

Comment: @jeroen: No. the above content is the whole thing.

Comment: Well, you can't run jQuery functions like `$.post()` without including jQuery first.

Comment: Thanks. Let me include jQuery. I will search how to include it.

Comment: @jeroen: OK. I've included it. Is there any more I need to do? Because I still don't get temp file. I've updated **g.htm**

Comment: You should open the browser console and check if you post variables to PHP file, than you need to check if you get those variables in PHP, than to check if your PHP file has permission to write other files...

Comment: @skobaljic: Thanks. I get 'no element found' for both my.php and 'g.htm'. I changed type="text/javascript" to language="javascript". tried. Then changed $_POST to $_GET in php with no luck. I don't know if I am incapable of this since I am searching for this about 8 hours.

Comment: I am sure you can do it, maybe read some tutorials/examples first: [Beginner's Guide to AJAX](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php), [AJAX with JSON return](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/), [jQuery AJAX write to file on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258750/jquery-ajax-save-to-file)

Comment: @skobaljic: Thank you for your kind words and thank you for the links

Comment: @skobaljic And thank you for teach me to fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add jQuery library in the `<head>` first:

```
<head>
   ..
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js/jquery.min.js">
   ..
</head>
```

Then, try this with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "my.php",
  data: { postres: res }
});
```

Comment: whew! You saved my life for the thing that I was hitting the wall for hours with $.post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try $temp = sys_get_temp_dir(); in your php file.

Comment: Also be sure you are accessing the correct temp directory.

Comment: Thank you. I'll certainly do.